# How much of what Dr. Rhonda Patrick's advice is accepted science vs speculation about potential goodness?

Tags: diet

Dr. Rhonda Patrick is a PhD who has conducted research into how to slow down ageing using nutrition - i came across her on a JRE podcast : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxM_CLsvieE&t=6580s

She founded 'foundmyfitness' : https://www.youtube.com/user/FoundMyFitness

Where she talks a lot about how nutrition can help slow down and prevent ageing.

My question is - how much of what she says is true? Is she the next Mehmet Oz, or is she for real?